# How to re-use the same default argument in multiple function declarations?

Tags: c++, default-arguments

What is the idiomatic way to re-use the same value as a default argument in multiple function declarations?

#### Use case

This comes up in the following use case: I have three string trim functions that either take a custom function or that trim spaces by default.  Specifying the same lambda expression 4 times makes the code difficult to read and maintain.

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
[[nodiscard]] auto trim_left(std::string str,
                             std::function<bool(const char)> left = [](const char c){return !std::isspace(c);}) -> std::string;
[[nodiscard]] auto trim_right(std::string str,
                              std::function<bool(const char)> right = [](const char c){return !std::isspace(c);}) -> std::string;
[[nodiscard]] auto trim(std::string str,
                        std::function<bool(const char)> left = [](const char c){return !std::isspace(c);},
                        std::function<bool(const char)> right = [](const char c){return !std::isspace(c);}) -> std::string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just give the default argument a name, like this:

```
auto def = [](const char c){return !std::isspace(c);};
```

and then use it as the default value:

```
[[nodiscard]] auto trim_left(std::string str,
                             std::function<bool(const char)> left = def) -> std::string;
[[nodiscard]] auto trim_right(std::string str,
                              std::function<bool(const char)> right = def) -> std::string;
[[nodiscard]] auto trim(std::string str,
                        std::function<bool(const char)> left = def,
                        std::function<bool(const char)> right = def) -> std::string;
```

You could name the function signature type as well, like this:

```
using fun = std::function<bool(const char)>;
```

and then the functions are even easier to read:

```
[[nodiscard]] auto trim_left(std::string str, fun left = def) -> std::string;
[[nodiscard]] auto trim_right(std::string str, fun right = def) -> std::string;
[[nodiscard]] auto trim(std::string str, fun left = def, fun right = def) -> std::string;
```